# Help identifying a varistor

Tags: varistor

Hi I am trying to identify what I think is a varistor. The problem I am having is the markings, other than the voltage don't seem to corrolate with anything. So I'm not sure if it is a varistor or if it just has obscure markings.
The markings are :
05
K385
1146
I know the k385 is the voltage from what I can find, but have no idea what the current is or what part number it matches up with. It's currently part of the 12v input on an electric fence energiser.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

That looks like the [TDK-EPCOS](https://en.tdk.eu/) logo (found on a Google image search for "varistor logo"). They happen to make varistors which makes it even more plausible.

[image]

Why is your sample stuck in a tortilla? I can see the herbs.

Comment: It's a varitilla!

Comment: interesting background analysis, but the brand logo is irrelevant to finding/choosing/locating a suitable lightning transient replacement (warning opinion)

Comment: I didn't think knowing the manufacturer is irrelevant, @Tony. OP couldn't trace the part number and, so, doesn't know the specs which, in turn, makes choosing a replacement a guessing game. Having the manufacturer's name both narrows the search to their datasheets and gives the option of contacting the manufacturer directly.

Comment: It is irrelevant also because TDK no longer makes this part but do support 05 series (lowest Joule rating ) in lower V,, but now I have a sudden urge to make Burritos

Comment: OK. Let's let others decide if it's relevant or not.

Comment: well it was useful for me to support my suggested replacement being available and 30x better absorption, thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's an EPCOS *(now TDK)* brand  MOV. The 05 is not the Joule rating, it indicates the series name which is **S05**. Here's the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/400/SIOV_Leaded_AdvanceD-525613.pdf). Measure its diameter and lead distance, you can find it in the datasheet. I think its part number is this: B72205S0381K101

Comment: Thanks, it's 4mm thick by about 5mm wide , the problem is that size doesn't match anything near in the 385v section.

Comment: good find Rohat. ! If it were me with an electric fence energizer, I'd still chose the 630 Joules rated part , which I selected .Also  the 05 series and 07 series were both dropped by TDK from the 385V rated devices presumeably due to whimpy Joule ratings <25 Joules and the negligible cost differences.

Answer (score 3):

Metal OXide Variators (MOV)  or now generically referred to as SIOV's are commonly rated by their RMS withstanding voltage or 385Vac in this case, then above this by a Joule rating 05 (which seems low).

- then followed by a date code YYWW for year and week.

These must follow a transient filter and current limiting, otherwise they may fail frequently or sooner than expected with limited number of Joules protection cycles.  This one is <5 yrs old in photo, consider the largest Joule rating of radial thruhole 385V MOV for replacement. (low cost)

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/littelfuse-inc/V25S385P/F7181-ND/2297519. .. good choice for lightning protection.  22kA  625 Joules 385Vac working voltage